# NullPointer Exception when importing backup of reports -- Jasperserver

Tags: linux, jasperserver

I'm on a Linux machine.

Running the  import script `sudo ./js-import.sh --input-zip ~/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/jasperbackup.zip`

when in the `/buildomatic` folder

gives me the following message:

> Using CE setup Using Bundled version of Java First resource
>   path:/home/myname/jasperreports-server-cp-5.1.0/buildomatic/conf_source/ieCe/applicationContext-cascade.xml
>
> Started to load resources Resource name: applicationContext.xml
>   Resource name: applicationContext-cascade.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-data-snapshots.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-events-logging.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-export-config.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-export-import.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-logging.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-olap-connection.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-report-scheduling.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-search.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-security.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-themes.xml Resource name:
>   applicationContext-virtual-data-source.xml Creating ActionModelService
>   object. Creating action model infrastructure.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.zip.ZipFile.getInputStream(ZipFile.java:180) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.io.ZipFileInput.getFileInputStream(ZipFileInput.java:74)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.getIndexInput(ImporterImpl.java:205)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.readIndexDocument(ImporterImpl.java:175)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.process(ImporterImpl.java:118)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImporterImpl.performImport(ImporterImpl.java:98)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImportCommandImpl.process(ImportCommandImpl.java:58)
>     at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.BaseExportImportCommand.process(BaseExportImportCommand.java:94) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.export.ImportCommand.main(ImportCommand.java:43)

Java is updated so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Since I'm on a LINUX machine, is there a way to write the import script to use a `.tar.gz`? Maybe that will work.

Comment: Have you checked the zip file? It may be corrupted.

Comment: @allprog I don't believe it is but is there a quick way to check if it is or not? This machine is a linux machine. Would that have something to do with it?

Comment: Create a minimalistic app that opens the file with the ZipFile class. This Gist may do it https://gist.github.com/andrask/5748920